# MySQL coalesce with extra condition

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a result set of several columns that may or may or may not have nulls. I want the first non null result that is greater than 1, what's the best way to add this secondary condition when coalescing my columns?

e.g.

```
result:
col1 col2 col3
1    null  2
null 1     3    
null null  4
```

returns 2 3 and 4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

lad2025's answer is correct, and you have to have an if for each column.  But, since you have to have those if functions anyway, you might as well do

```
SELECT IF(col1>1, col1, if(col2>1, col2, if (col3>1, col3, null)))
```

or similarly

```
SELECT CASE WHEN col1>1 THEN col1
       WHEN col2>1 THEN col2
       WHEN col3>1 THEN col3
       ELSE null END
```

Either of these will be a little more efficient and takes less code than using coalesce because you would then still have to use the if to null out any values of 1 in any column

Comment: You can't use multiple `ELSE` and no need the last `ELSE` neither, by default will return `null`.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza You are right about the redundant ELSE's, a brain hiccup. corrected.  But I leave the null because I have always found that more readable.

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT COALESCE(IF(col1>1,col1, NULL), IF(col2>1, col2, NULL), IF(col3>1, col3, NULL))
FROM tab
```

Comment: if i want to scale this to several columns will i have to add an if for each columns?

Comment: Yes you will need to add them

Comment: @MiloHou You should probably redesign your table if there are lots of similar columns like this. They should probably be a new table, with a separate row for each value.

Comment: @Barmar i have 4 columns to do this for, and depending on the result of this case a different value for the other columns in my desired result too. Will repeating this large Case statement multiple times in the code be optimized by the RDBMS?

Comment: The `CASE` statement doesn't affect how the query selects data from the DB. It will only be executed on the rows that are selected.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it with a single `CASE` statement:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN IFNULL(col1, 0) > 1 THEN col1
            WHEN IFNULL(col2, 0) > 1 THEN col2
            WHEN IFNULL(col3, 0) > 1 THEN col3
       END
FROM mytable
```

The cases could also be written as:

```
            WHEN colN IS NOT NULL AND colN > 1 THEN colN
```

Comment: You do not need to test for null if you are testing for > 1

Answer (score 2):

you can use nullif

```
SELECT COALESCE(
        NULLIF(col1, 1),
        NULLIF(col2, 1),
        NULLIF(col3, 1))
```

[**SQL FIDDLE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/89fd2/1)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT CASE
           WHEN COL1 IS NOT NULL and COL1 > 1 THEN COL1
           WHEN COL2 IS NOT NULL and COL2 > 1 THEN COL2
           WHEN COL3 IS NOT NULL and COL3 > 1 THEN COL3
       END
```

Comment: You're not testing whether they're greater than 1.

Comment: @Barmar Thanks. Is better now?

Comment: You don't need to check for null if you are checking for >1

Comment: Yes, i saw your answer. I'm checking why is that. Usually in C# I always check for null first..